# Which derailler hanger?

Tags: sram, derailleur-hanger

Which derailler hanger should work on saracen raw 3 with sram sx4 rear derailer? The old derailler snapped off rhe frame

Comment: https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/all-derailleur-hangers.html

Comment: It is disappointing when this happens, but consider that now you're shopping for a hanger, not a new frame.   Do you still have the old hanger?  Can you add a couple of clear photos to this question ?

Comment: Your snapped hanger my have a number like the ones from Wheels mfg. Match the number. If not, you may find spec sheet with that info online or you might inquire from their site,  --->   https://www.saracen.co.uk/contact

Answer (score 2):

These claim to fit the Saracen Raw 2, which appears to be the same frame with slightly different components. It looks right based on what I can find on the internet.

The compatibility of a hanger is between it and the frame, in general, standard rear derailleurs are compatible with all hangers.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SARACEN-Mantra-Raw-2-MONGOOSE-Tyax-Comp-Super-Rear-Gear-Mech-Hanger-CC003-/301758510575

[image: Hanger]

Comment: The derailler was part of the frame itself, i contacted saracen directly but they havr been takrn over by new comoany and dont have record prior to 2009. Will there still be code?

Comment: There should be, do you have any pictures of the back end of the bike/derailleur hanger?